# Convert float to long in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, long-integer

I'm using Unity3D to develop a mobile game with cross-platform, i.e. Android and iOS.
It's written in C#.

One of the variable is calculated as following:

```
long hp;
int lv;
hp = (long)Math.Pow(1.5f, lv);
```

The code works well on PC and Android. but not in iOS. In iOS, even when `lv=0`, the value of `hp` will become something like 46071824188000017409.

I tried to debug it with Xcode, the value of `Math.Pow(1.5f, lv)` has no problem, so the problem is long-conversion. I tried to use `System.Convert.ToInt64` and it appears the same.

The problem exists on both iOS6 and iOS7. Anyone knows how to deal with this?

EDIT: Here are some more debugs:

```
float temp = Mathf.Pow(1.5f, lv); //returns 1
long temp2 = (long)temp; //returns 4607182418800017409
```

Comment: What does `Math.Pow(1.5f, lv)` return?

Comment: `1` when `lv=0`, if I dont use `(long)`, the result will becomes `46071824188000017409` even `lv=0` if I use `(long)`

Comment: The results are both `46071824188000017409` for `Debug.Log(hp);` and `Debug.Log((long)Math.Pow(1.5f, lv));`

Comment: `Debug.Log((long)lv);` returns `1` when `lv=1`